# Outputting directly to template with Embedded Javascript Syntax

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm using Backbone with Underscore templates. I have a JavaScript `if()` condition in my code that looks something like this:

```
<div class='faces'>
    <% if(somevalue === true) { %>
       your face
    <% } else { %>
       my face
    <% } %>
</div>
```

However I find this syntax awkward and I really would like to use something like the following, even though it doesn't actually work (replaces entire document with the text):

```
<div class='faces'>
    <% if(somevalue === true) { 
        document.write("your face");
    } else { 
        document.write("my face");
    }
</div>
```

I want the string to be output in the template exactly where it is called. For outputting a simple variable EJS (and underscore) have a great syntax of

```
<%= somevalue %>
```

Where the `=` is the critical part that `document.write()`s it out into the template. Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? Can JavaScript output inline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options, you could use `<%= %>` and a ternary:

```
<%= somevalue == true ? 'your face' : 'my face' %>
```

or you could use [`print`](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> You can also use `print` from within JavaScript code. This is sometimes more convenient than using `<%= ... %>`.
>
> ```
> var compiled = _.template("<% print('Hello ' + epithet); %>");
> compiled({epithet: "stooge"});
> => "Hello stooge."
> ```

so you could do this:

```
<% if(somevalue == true) { 
    print("your face");
} else { 
    print("my face");
} %>
```

I'm assuming that `if(somevalue = true)` is a typo and should be `if(somevalue == true)`.

Comment: Fantastic! Print is what I needed. Ternary is not flexible enough for the real scenario, but handy to keep in mind. I didn't actually know any other commands in JS to output to the DOM. Thank you mu!

Comment: @MikeMurko: `print` is actually specific to Underscore templates and is around precisely for your situation.