# Style tags and Javascript in Template files

Tags: node.js, express, coding-style, separation-of-concerns, convention

I'm looking through a project built by a foreign team. I am looking through some of the template files ending in ".ejs" and ".tmp", but from my limited knowledge, there is some bad convention here, can some of you confirm? Here are a few things I see on each template file:

1) The doctype, html tags and head are re-defined in each template file (stylesheet and JS files are linked on every one, but a different number of stylesheets and JS files linked depending on which template file it is).

2) there are Style Tags with a bunch of CSS in it, and Script tags with Javascript in it. So I'm guessing they did that because they only need those styles/JS in that particular template, but isn't it bad convention?

This is a node/express app I'm talking about. Is this a sign of bad convention/organization, or is it some sort of performance enhancement/convention I do not understand? Please advise me on this!

Comment: .ejs files you are watching it nothing but partials of EJS templates. ExpressJS supports Jade, EJS template engines. EJS looks very much similar to normal HTML so don't be confused. :)

Comment: So which specific template files should I be looking at, if not .ejs files?

Comment: Express supports some of the templating engines by default like Jade and Express but if you want with Angularjs template or handlebars or any other templating engines then it upto you, you can hook it and that will work for you. So it's about your choice. If you can explain clearly what you are trying to build then it will be more clear.

Comment: I am looking through an app built by someone else, with a lot of EJS templates. I am wondering, lets say I was to edit one of the templates, where would I do that? Would it be directly on the .EJS files or are they put somewhere else?

Comment: It should be directly on the EJS file. It is very easy to get started, look here(http://www.embeddedjs.com)

Comment: So my question is, if there are a bunch of <style> and <script> tags in the EJS file itself, is it bad convention?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Outputting directly to template with Embedded Javascript Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766882/outputting-directly-to-template-with-embedded-javascript-syntax)